# gufw - rules listed in red and green. What do these colors mean

Tags: ufw, gufw

In the gufw rules table listing, some rules are printed in red and some in green. What is the meaning of these two colors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GUFW uses colors to quickly identify what type of rule you are looking at.

- Green = Deny
- Red = Allow
- Blue = Reject
- Yellow = Limit
- Black = No rule set

*Note: These rules are just some default ones I stuck in here for the purpose of the screenshot, and are not meant to be seen as recommendations.*

[image]